# VueJS: watching two properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, watch

Suppose I have two data properties:

```
data() {
  return {
    a: false, 
    b: false, 
  }
}
```

When `a` and `b` become `true` at the same time, I want to carry out a related task.

How can I use a `watch` method in Vue to achieve this?

Answer (score 29):

Watch a computed value.

```
computed:{
    combined(){
        return this.a && this.b
    }
}
watch:{
    combined(value){
        if (value)
            //do something
    }
}
```

There is a sort of short hand for the above using [$watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch).

> ```
> vm.$watch(
>   function () {
>     return this.a + this.b
>   },
>   function (newVal, oldVal) {
>     // do something
>   }
> )
> ```

Comment: Is it still only way to do it or is there any update from vue ?

Comment: @berkan I don't know. I haven't had the chance to work in Vue for a while.

Comment: Smartest solution combining computed properties and watchers. Thanks! :)

Comment: Using combined computed field this way looks completely wrong. If a=true and b=false and then they change to a=false and b=true or a=false and b=false, the watcher will not execute as the combined value will still be false... For not to mention that this is very specyfic to bool values. Though the approach by itself is pretty valid - you just need to find correct way to generate combined value. For example, `combined(){ return [this.a, this.b]; }` should work with pretty much any basic type values (probably will not work with objects - `JSON.stringify([a, b])` should work in this case)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much the same solution as @Bert suggested. But you can just do the following:

```
data() {
  return {
      combined: {
          a: false, 
          b: false, 
      }
  }
},
```

Then:

```
watch: {
    combined:{
        deep:true,
        handler
    }
}
```